# Pin html div at the current position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of images and while clicking any image a pop-up div appears. Now I want to pin these divs at their current position on a button click on the respective divs.
Say I want to pin 2 pop-up say "P" divs. First I click an image, P1 appears , then I pin it on its current location by clicking a button on this div and then same way I click another image,another similar pop-up div P2 appears, then I pin it on its current location.

I tried to change the position of div to "fixed" on button click, but its not working.
I searched and found jquery.pin.js. Can this be used in my case or any other solution.. Please help..

Comment: you have to share you code first.

Comment: Share your code, `position: fixed` should work, you most likely have a bug somewhere.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)